# Commas in cookie value being double parsed in ZF2

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2, setcookie

I am using ZF2's [Zend\HTTP\Header\SetCookie class](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Http.Header.SetCookie.html) to set a named cookie. The catch is that the value is a comma separated list of single word values. This has been working fine to date like this:

```
$translations_cookie = new SetCookie('translations', implode(',', $requested_translations), null, null, null, false, false, null, null);
$response->getHeaders()->addHeader($translations_cookie);
```

The cookie value gets encoded and the commas become `%2C` and all is well across browsers. Retrieving the value later and splitting on commas works just fine.

The trouble is that cookie doesn't have a the path value defined and it defaults to whatever folder it was run from. I just ran into a situation where that breaks and I need to force the cookie path to be the site root. I thought this would be as simple as adding the correct value:

```
$translations_cookie = new SetCookie('translations', implode(',', $requested_translations), null, '/', null, false, false, null, null);
$response->getHeaders()->addHeader($translations_cookie);
```

That seems to set the path just fine, but now the cookie value is messed up! Only the *last* item in the array is making it through to the actual cookie that gets set. No matter how many items are in the array they are discarded and only the last item comes across in the cookie header.

Any idea what's up and how I fix it? Is this a bug in ZF2 or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** Yes I've tried pre-encoding the value using `urlencode()` before passing it to the cookie function but this didn't change the end result. Using a different delimiter does fix this issue with Zend but it creates an incompatibility between other parts of my program including third party code and existing URLs and would mean I have to version the cookies and update old sessions—a circus I don't want to join if I can help it.

Comment: You probably did this already, but I'd just set a var like $cookieVal to implode(',', $requested_translations), var_dump it, and confirm that it is still what you think it is right before you set the cookie.

Comment: @AlexMA Yes I confirmed that already.

Comment: What is the value of `$translations_cookie->getValue()`? Also, what version of ZF2 is this? I looked over the zf2 master source code for the SetCookie class and the Headers class and nothing stood out yet, but perhaps there's a bug in an older version.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `$requested_translations` so i can recreate the issue?

Answer (score -1):

This may sound dumb, but just delete cookies or try another browser (not private browser) :)